# Interacting with gnuplot from a C program. How to type in an array to plot

Tags: c, gnuplot

I am trying to use gnuplot to make a 'live' plot embedded in a C application, but I have encountered something that I want to change.

I am using [gnuplot_i](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/index.html) to 'interface' with gnuplot as if I were using gnuplot in the terminal.
Whenever I plot (two lines) I save the data to a file to then tell gnuplot to load the file and plot.

I would like to not have to save a data file and load the data directly into gnuplot. I do not know much of gnuplot so there may be a simple solution for what I want. What I would like is to have a command like this:

```
plot [1,2,3,4], [1,1,1,1], [1,2,3,4], [2,2,2,2]
     |_____line 1_______|  |______line 2______|
```

Is there a way to do this in gnuplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gnuplot> help datablock
 There are two mechanisms for embedding data into a stream of gnuplot commands.
 If the special filename '-' appears in a plot command, then the lines
 immediately following the plot command are interpreted as inline data.
 See `special-filenames`.  Data provided in this way can only be used once, by
 the plot command it follows.

 The second mechanism defines a named data block as a here-document.  The named
 data is persistent and may be referred to by more than one plot command.
 Example:
      $Mydata << EOD
      11 22 33 first line of data
      44 55 66 second line of data
      # comments work just as in a data file
      77 88 99
      EOD
      stats $Mydata using 1:3
      plot $Mydata using 1:3 with points, $Mydata using 1:2 with impulses

 Data block names must begin with a $ character, which distinguishes them from
 other types of persistent variables.  The end-of-data delimiter (EOD in the
 example) may be any sequence of alphanumeric characters.
```